# How to call a NSNotificationCenter function in another view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I watch an NSNotification from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113533/can-i-watch-an-nsnotification-from-another-class)

I am currently using this code below in my appDelegate.m file:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(handleEnteredBackground:) 
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object: nil];

}
```

However, I want it to call a selector in my viewController.m file. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you register the notification first, in your viewController.m `init` method (or somewhere else appropriate):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(someMethod:) 
                                             name: @"NotificationNameHere"
                                           object: nil];
```

In your App Delegate, fire the notification:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification: @"NotificationNameHere"];

}
```

Comment: doesn't work - says this: http://pastie.org/2932035

Comment: The system already generates UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
notifications when the app goes into background, there is no need to generate new ones.

Answer (score 2):

in your viewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   [super viewDidLoad];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                     selector: @selector(handleEnteredBackground:) 
                                         name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                       object: nil];
}
```

Comment: This is a simpler way of doing it, as iOS handles firing the notification on `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`.

Answer (score 1):

just add this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                     selector: @selector(handleEnteredBackground:) 
                                         name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                       object: nil];
```

in your viewController.m viewDidLoad method. (don't forget to create handleEnteredBackground: method)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to register your app delegate for entering background notifications, you already get callbacks for that. It makes even less sense to register your app delegate for these notifications *in that callback*. You can just, as other posters have suggested add your viewController object as an observer on init (and don't forget to remove yourself on dealloc or you will get bad accesses).

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to access to the delegate from a viewController, you can do:

```
MYAppDelegate *delegate = (MYAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate selectorName];
```

...otherwise clarify your question :P

Comment: no, it's to access the viewController selector from the delegate file. I need the "handleEnteredBackground:" to go to my viewController file, whereas at the moment, it's looking for it in my appDelegate.h file.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. You need to register the notification in the object you expect it, then you fire it when appropriate.